# Getting started with VNC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc

I have subscribed to a VPS service for the purpose of running some remote applications.  To do this I'm going to need a remote desktop of one sort or another.

With this in mind it was suggested that I try Ubuntu.  The installation that was prepared for me was Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit (Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 2.6.18-348.4.1.el5.028stab107.1 x86_64))

From here I used `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` which completed successfully.  I rebooted the machine and reconnected via ssh.

When I attempt to connect from TightVNC on my Windows machine I get a message about the session being actively refused.

What should I do to confirm the service is running?  Do I need to setup a firewall rule to allow the ports to pass through?

(I am a linux newb so explicitness is appreciated)

Comment: Try adding the session id to the target-ip. that should do it.

Comment: @M.Bennett: How do I go about finding the session id and what format would I then use as the input for target ip?  session-id@target-ip?

Comment: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:sessionid, probably :1

Comment: @josten what do you mean by tainting? slowing it down? making it insecure?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a fair amount of time looking for an answer to this, and while I think that this is probably not the optimal way to achieve the goal, it certainly works.

In essence `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` is insufficient.

We must add a vnc server, such as `apt-get install tightvncserver` which can then be started by using the `vncserver` command.

The source of the information [is here](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1029327)